# How can I create custom decals using Decal Machine?

Tags: texturing, add-on, error

I just tried to create a decal but I get an error in the console:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\DECALmachine\operators\create.py", line 162, in execute
> packed, decaltype = core.pack_textures(dm, decalpath, textures, size)

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
> location: :-1

Does anyone know why this happen? How to make it work?

Comment: Given that this question is about a paid addon, you should contact the developer directly for support (or get your money back)

Comment: Same issue, did u solve it